# how to exclude specific category types (uncategorized) from blog page?

Tags: categories

[image: Screenshot showing 'Posted in Uncategorized']

I made one blog post page and 2 second page I made for uncategorized category page using this file category-uncategorized.php and now I want to remove this all uncategorized category from blog page.

and here is a code

```
<?php if(have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();
        get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
    endwhile;?>
    <?php echo bootstrap_pagination($query) ?>
<?php else :
    echo '<p>No Content Found</p>';
    endif;?>
```

Comment: When you say you "made one blog post page" do you mean you made a Page in wp-admin and you are showing all the Posts within that Page? Or do you just mean you created a Post in the Uncategorized Category, and now that post is showing up on your front page a.k.a. the "Posts page"? In either case you could use `pre_get_posts` to change the query on whichever URL you are talking about, to exclude that category.

Answer (score 0):

Please try code given below:

```
function blog_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'blog_exclude_category' );
```

Add this in your functions.php